# How to call a R function, who's name will be called from variable

Tags: r

I had a R functions with name  like "Apple", Banana", etc.., I would like to call this functions from a variable (declared in a web UI) called "fruit" in which I will pass those function name.
So whatever function name, I provided, that corresponding function had to be executed.
When I'm trying to execute the variable as function like 
Fruit <- Fruits(x,t,y)
Then its is giving error "Fruit" function doesn't exist. I too know it doesn't exist. Point is, I would like to call the function who's name is inside the "Fruit" variable.
moreover, When I check the "class" of fruit, it say it is "character", it's right, but fortunately, there is a function name, in this variable.
Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: You need to make your question understandable by using a good formatting.Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You may need `get`. Here is a example: `Fruit <- 'mean'; get(Fruit)(1:10)   # 5.5`

Comment: Or `match.fun`.

Comment: Axeman, can u please spare 5 min with me thru webex, i still unable to make it done. plzzzzz

Comment: I tried Axeman, But thought there is a function, it is saying that the function doesn't exist.
If possible, plz connect thru webex

Comment: I'm trying to trigger the model thru variable using "get" by setting the working directory to current folder, I able to trigger the model with its name, ,but when tried thru get, its stating error, 
object '<file_name>.r' not found, 
Please help me